# How to add transparent background on Canvas text in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, android-bitmap

I want to add transparent `canvas` on the price quote. Exactly we can see in following picture ($74). I tried to follow SO question but nothing was working for me. Here is my `code`:

[image]

```
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    synchronized (ImageTransform.class) {
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Bitmap resultBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_heart);
        bitmapImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, 50, 50, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextSize(40);
        paint.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawText("$250", 20, 400, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapImage, 510, 55, null);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return resultBitmap;
    }
```

How can I add a transparent color or image on price section?

## Edit-1

However I am able to add canvas rectangle but not at the right position

```
 Paint paintrect = new Paint();
        paintrect.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paintrect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paintrect.setStrokeWidth(10);

        float left = 20;
        float top = 80;
        float right = 50;
        float bottom = 0;

        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paintrect);
```

I got this :
You can see black rectangle on top-left of image.
[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!

```
Paint paintrect = new Paint();
    paintrect.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paintrect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paintrect.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paintrect.setAlpha(127);

    float left = 18;
    float top = 360;
    float right = 128;
    float bottom = 416;

    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paintrect);
```

You will have to tweak the rectangle coordinates to get it right where you want; I estimated as best I could.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. `paint.setAlpha()` making $250 transparent or non-transparent. What I asked for adding a background rectangle box on it (little bit transparent). As you can see in the above image

Comment: Please check out the Edit section

Comment: I did misunderstand your question.  Please see my updated answer.